# Execution policy problem with lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++17

I have this class:

```
class EMX_Counter {
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<WireBase>> WiresList;
    public:
        EMX_Counter(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<WireBase>>& w) : WiresList(w) {}
        EMX_Counter(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<WireBase>>&& w) : WiresList(std::move(w)) {}
        std::future<std::vector<double>> getEmxEfficiency();
    };
```

The `WireBase` is an abstract class (not important here how it works) and I need an unique ptr because I need polymorphism. That said, `getEmxEfficiency()` takes some time because the vector contains at least 28'000 / 30'000 items and one single call to the method is slow.

I have decided to use a parallel approach to speed up and this is the result:

```
std::future<std::vector<double>> EMX_Counter::getEmxEfficiency()  {
        return std::async([*this]() {
            std::vector<double> temp;               

            std::for_each(std::execution::par, WiresList.begin(), WiresList.end(), [&](auto& PolyObject) {
                double result = PolyObject->getPartialEfficiency();
                //more time-expensive operations
                temp.push_back( result );
            });

            return temp;
        });
    }
```

The call `PolyObject->getPartialEfficiency();` returns a double and does not throw exceptions, it is "safe".

---

I am using the latest Visual Studio version (updated yesterday) and the flag `/std:c++17`. The problem is that I get this error:

```
 std::unique_ptr<WireBase,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const
 std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to
 reference a deleted function (file: xmemory0).
```

- What could this be?
- I have captured `[*this]` in the lambda so I have a copy of the object and I am sure (am I?) that there won't be problems with the async execution. Should I capture by value of reference instead?

In the `for_each` lambda I have captured by reference because temp is in scope and I won't have problems with it being destroyed.

Comment: "_I have captured [*this] in the lambda so I have a copy of the object_" This is precisely the problem. The copy-constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is deleted, and the act of copying `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>` requires copy-constructor of `std::unique_ptr` to be available.

Comment: Your unique_ptr is not unique! Change it to shared_ptr and it will work

Comment: `EMX_Counter(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<WireBase>>& w) : WiresList(w) {}` This already ain't gonna work, as you try to copy `unique_ptr` instances from the argument into your list.

Comment: If and when you get past the compilation problem, note that you have a data race: multiple threads are pushing onto `temp` vector with no synchronization.

Comment: Lifetime question; is the return value of `std::future<std::vector<double>> getEmxEfficiency()` expected to be valid *after* `EMX_Counter` has been destroyed or not?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE]s, things like completely non-working parts of your code make it hard to distinguish "the OP actually intended that" from "the OP made a mistake in pseudo-code".

Answer (score 1):

I should use this code instead:

```
//global
auto mymutex = std::mutex{};

std::future<std::vector<double>> EMX_Counter::getEmxEfficiency()  {
    return std::async([=]() {
        std::vector<double> temp;               

        std::for_each(std::execution::par, WiresList.begin(), WiresList.end(), [&](auto& PolyObject) {

            //your code...

            auto lock = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{ mymutex };
            temp.push_back( result );
        });

        return temp;
    });
}
```

Where `WiresList` is declared as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<WireBase>>`. Now the variable is protected and I have no more compile time problems because there is a shared pointer!

Comment: A global variable that isn't used?  Well, really, suggesting a global variable seems like a bad plan.

Comment: So now, a global variable guarding actions done on a single vector within a single mutex in a single class?  Why in the world would you use a global variable there?